# How to make a GET request to ContextualWeb image search API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, search

I am using [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/contextualwebsearch/api/web-search) to access **[ContextualWeb](https://contextualweb.io/) image search API**. The code examples which are given are for server side only:
https://rapidapi.com/contextualwebsearch/api/web-search/

I am trying to integrate the API in a React JS app. How can I make the GET request in **JavaScript**?

Here is a **CURL** example from the Rapid API web site:

```
curl --get --include 'https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?autoCorrect=false&pageNumber=1&pageSize=10&q=Taylor+Swift&safeSearch=false' \
  -H 'X-RapidAPI-Host: contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com' \
  -H 'X-RapidAPI-Key: XXXXXXXX'
```

The image search API should return a resulting JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given `curl` request translate to following [`fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)(implemented by browsers) request.

```
const url ="https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?autoCorrect=false&pageNumber=1&pageSize=10&q=Taylor+Swift&safeSearch=false"
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "XXXXXXXX"
  },
}

fetch(url, options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks again for the quick reply!